# dart event loop confused me

Tags: dart

Recently, I'm learning dart  **asynchronous programming**. When it comes to **event loop** part.
it have some code like below:

```dart
  new Future(() => print('future #3 of 4'))
      .then((_) => new Future(() => print('future #3a a new future')))
      .then((_) => print('future #3b'))
      .then((_) => print('future #3c'));

  new Future(() => print('future #4 of 4'))
      .then((_) { new Future(() => print('future #4a')); })
      .then((_) => print('future #4b'))
      .then((_) => print('future #4c'));
```

It's results like below:

```
future #3 of 4
future #4 of 4
future #4b
future #4c
future #3a a new future
future #3b
future #3c
future #4a
```

What make me confused have sth like below:

1. what's the difference below

```dart
(_) => new Future(() => print('future #3a a new future')))
```

and

```dart
(_) { new Future(() => print('future #4a')); }
```

2. why results as above.

I'm new to dart. Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two syntax is that this:

```
(_) => new Future(() => print('future #3a a new future')))
```

Is a shorthand syntax for doing this:

```
(_) {
  return new Future(() => print('future #3a a new future'));
})
```

Note the `return` which are not part of your second example. The problem with your code is that by omitting the `return` you change the flow of your code since the spawned `Future` no longer are getting a `Future` it should wait on.

By adding the missing `return` your code will output:

```
future #3 of 4
future #4 of 4
future #3a a new future
future #3b
future #3c
future #4a
future #4b
future #4c
```